# How to efficiently identify the starting and ending index of a run in a stratified boolean array?

Tags: algorithm, search

While there are plenty of algorithms for finding longest contiguous subsequence, and longest repeating value, my problem is slightly different, and I am thinking that its constraints could allow for improved performance.

Let’s say I have an array of boolean values, with the following constraints:

1. Somewhere within the array there might exist a single contiguous subsequence of “true” values of unknown length. Every other value is guaranteed to be “false”.
2. The run might not exist at all, meaning the entire array consists of “false” values.

I need to identify the start and end indices of this run. The array could have thousands of items, perhaps even hundreds of thousands, so a linear search is not efficient enough, and building an index in-memory is not ideal.

Here are some example situations, with 0 representing “false” and 1 representing “true”

`00001111110`

`00000000000`

`11111111110`

`11111111111`

`10000000000`

`00001110000`

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? An ideal solution would not use additional memory, and be sublinear in runtime.

Comment: Do you want more efficient on some sort of ideal computer, or a real one?

Those answers are very, very different.

Comment: In order to know for sure that there aren't any 1s, you need to look at every single element.  If the worst case complexity is what you care about, you can't do better than linear time.

Comment: For the record, doing 64 bits at a time of a boolean array with `xor` commands will let you process hundreds of thousands of records looking for any trues in a few microseconds.  Not sure you need anything more clever than that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this problem is similar to determining an unknown interval within a known range. It can be optimized to complete in as fast as `O(log n)` time for intervals of the same order of magnitude as those ranges they are placed in. But in order to spot the tiniest of intervals (1 unit long), or to rule out all possible intervals (if there's none), you still have to brute force through the entire array, so the worst case scenario requires `O(n)` time.

As for space complexity, you can indeed solve it using fixed `O(1)` memory.

**Here's the algorithm:**

1. Check boundaries of the range. If both belong to the interval, we're done. If only the left, go to `Step 4`. If only the right, go to `Step 3`. If none, go to `Step 2`.
2. Locate *any* index within the interval using [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to locate/rule out larger intervals first<sup>[1]</sup>. Start checking indices within the initial range by first splitting it by the largest power of 2 that fits. Then decrease the power and check indices *between* those checked in previous loops<sup>[2]</sup>. Repeat the search until you find some position inside the interval, or nothing is left to check (in the latter case, finish with "not found" result). Once you have the position, you know that the interval *must* lie between already checked elements. Perform `Step 3` and `Step 4`.
3. Use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to locate the *leftmost* point of the interval. Search between the index known to be inside the interval, and the closest index to the left known to be outside. This step takes `O(log n)` time.
4. Same as `Step 3`, but search for the *rightmost* point.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Guaranteed to stumble upon any interval of length `m` in `O(n/m)` time.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Using powers of 2 is very handy here because you don't need to keep track of previously accessed indices.</sub>

---

Some commentary on the demo below:

- `EXHAUSTIVE TEST` checks if all possible intervals within all ranges up to 100 units long are correctly determined.
- `INCREMENTAL TEST` shows how the number of operations can vary for tiny intervals depending on their location within the search range. This is a direct result of BFS jumping over the same places again and again, and decreasing its leaps until eventually it hits the proper index.
- `RANDOM TEST` demonstrates how speed of search effectively grows when interval-to-range ratio also increases. Here I generate intervals with lengths from `109` to `1014` within the range of `1015`. Despite that those numbers look big, the demo proves that ratio matters more than magnitude. You can see how it takes a little more than mere 100 operations to determine `1014` intervals within `1015` range.

```js
function createOpaqueInterval (rangeStart, rangeEnd, intervalStart, intervalEnd) {

    if (rangeStart > rangeEnd) {
        [rangeStart, rangeEnd] = [rangeEnd, rangeStart];
    }
    if (intervalStart > intervalEnd) {
        [intervalStart, intervalEnd] = [intervalEnd, intervalStart];
    }

    intervalStart = Math.max(intervalStart, rangeStart);
    intervalEnd = Math.min(intervalEnd, rangeEnd);
    return {
        rangeStart,
        rangeEnd,
        belongs: (index) => (index >= intervalStart && index < intervalEnd)
    };
}

function determineInterval (interval) {

    let rangeStart = interval.rangeStart;
    let rangeEnd = interval.rangeEnd;
    let rangeLength = rangeEnd - rangeStart;
    let intervalStart = NaN;
    let intervalEnd = NaN;
    let reads = 0;

    function belongs (index) { reads++; return interval.belongs(index); }
    function result () { return { intervalStart, intervalEnd, reads }; }

    if (rangeLength <= 0) {
        return result();
    }

    if (rangeLength == 1) {
        if (belongs(rangeStart)) {
            intervalStart = rangeStart;
            intervalEnd = rangeEnd;
        }
        return result();
    }

    function locateLeftmost (left, right) {

        while (left + 1 < right) {
            let mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
            if (belongs(mid)) {
                right = mid;
            }
            else {
                left = mid;
            }
        }
        intervalStart = right;
    }

    function locateRightmost (left, right) {

        while (left + 1 < right) {
            let mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
            if (belongs(mid)) {
                left = mid;
            }
            else {
                right = mid;
            }
        }
        intervalEnd = left + 1;
    }

    function locateAny () {

        let step = 1;
        while (step < rangeLength) { step += step; }

        for (let halfstep = step / 2; step > 1; step = halfstep, halfstep /= 2) {
            for (let mid = rangeStart + halfstep; mid < rangeEnd - 1; mid += step) {

                if (belongs(mid)) {
                    let left = mid - halfstep;
                    let right = Math.min(mid + halfstep, rangeEnd - 1);
                    locateLeftmost(left, mid);
                    locateRightmost(mid, right);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    let left = rangeStart;
    let right = rangeEnd - 1;
    let boundary = 0;

    if (belongs(left)) { intervalStart = left; boundary |= 2; }
    if (belongs(right)) { intervalEnd = right + 1; boundary |= 1; }

    switch (boundary) {
        case 0b00: locateAny(); break;
        case 0b01: locateLeftmost(left, right); break;
        case 0b10: locateRightmost(left, right); break;
    }

    return result();
}

function testSample (rangeStart, rangeEnd, intervalStart, intervalEnd) {

    let interval = createOpaqueInterval(rangeStart, rangeEnd, intervalStart, intervalEnd);
    let result = determineInterval(interval);
    let success = (result.intervalStart == intervalStart && result.intervalEnd == intervalEnd);

    console.log(`${success? 'SUCCESS': 'FAILURE'} >> start: ${result.intervalStart}, end: ${result.intervalEnd}, reads: ${result.reads}`);
}

function testExhaustive (maxRangeLength) {

    let testsPassed = 0;
    let testsFailed = 0;

    for (let rangeLength = 1; rangeLength <= maxRangeLength; rangeLength++) {
        for (let intervalStart = 0; intervalStart < rangeLength; intervalStart++) {
            for (let intervalEnd = intervalStart + 1; intervalEnd <= rangeLength; intervalEnd++) {

                let interval = createOpaqueInterval(0, rangeLength, intervalStart, intervalEnd);
                let result = determineInterval(interval);
                if (result.intervalStart == intervalStart && result.intervalEnd == intervalEnd) {
                    testsPassed++;
                }
                else {
                    testsFailed++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(`EXHAUSTIVE TEST...`
        + `\n> Max range length: ${maxRangeLength}`
        + `\n> Tests total: ${testsPassed + testsFailed}`
        + `\n> Tests passed: ${testsPassed}`
        + `\n> Tests failed: ${testsFailed}`
    );
}

function testIncremental (rangeLength, intervalStart, intervalLength, samples) {

    console.log(`INCREMENTAL TEST...`
        + `\n> Range length: ${rangeLength}`
        + `\n> Interval start: ${intervalStart}`
        + `\n> Interval length: ${intervalLength}`
        + `\n> Samples: ${samples}`
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
        testSample(0, rangeLength, intervalStart + i, intervalStart + intervalLength + i);
    }
}

function testRandom (rangeLength, intervalLength, samples) {

    console.log(`RANDOM TEST...`
        + `\n> Range length    : ${rangeLength}`
        + `\n> Interval length : ${intervalLength}`
        + `\n> Samples: ${samples}`
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
        let intervalStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * (rangeLength - intervalLength));
        testSample(0, rangeLength, intervalStart, intervalStart + intervalLength);
    }
}

testExhaustive(100);
testIncremental(1e6, 2e5, 1, 10);
testRandom(1e15, 1e9, 5);
testRandom(1e15, 1e10, 5);
testRandom(1e15, 1e11, 5);
testRandom(1e15, 1e12, 5);
testRandom(1e15, 1e13, 5);
testRandom(1e15, 1e14, 5);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```